# create a view with hard coded values without writing insert

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi i'm creating a view in the following way

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW tableA (field1, field2)
AS
  SELECT 
    CAST("state" AS        CHAR(2)),
    CAST("LOCALITY_NAME" AS   CHAR(31)),
  FROM tableB;
```

I need to add one more column called 'id' and populate it with hard coded value 'abc' for all the rows. Is it possible to do that while creating the view? I have seen [this thread](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/forum/threads/view-with-hard-coded-values.14433/) , but i was not able to understand how it fits in my case.

Comment: Is `CAST("state" AS CHAR(2))` a typo since `state` is longer than 2 charatcers?

Comment: no, state is column in table B and value in state column is <= 2 characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 'abc' as id,
        CAST("state" AS CHAR(2)),
        CAST(LOCALITY_NAME AS CHAR(31)),
FROM tableB
```

Comment: i also need to set the datatype of id as char(3). can i do that here itself?

Comment: I would have thought it is `char(3)` automatically. But can't say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just add it as a constanct value:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW tableA (field1, field2)
AS
  SELECT
    CAST("state" AS        CHAR(2)),
    CAST("LOCALITY_NAME" AS   CHAR(31)),
    'abc' AS id 
  FROM tableB;
```